# Sql Server Contains

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to match on a partial string but can't turn full-text indexing on so can't use contains. I've looked at Levenstein's function for determining the distance between two strings but I'm not looking for fuzzy matching but that every character in the column exists in the string.

I.e. If the string being passed is something like AB_SYS_20120430.TXT I want to match on any columns containing AB_SYS. The like predicate isn't getting me there.  I really need the equivalent of the .NET contains feature but as mentioned turning on full text indexing isn't an option to be turned on.  Thought I would see if there were any other possible work arounds.

Comment: why won't `LIKE` work for you?  I think that is what you want, but you will probably need to organize your data differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for the `LIKE` function?
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
... WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%AB_SYS%'
```

That may not be optimal, but it seems like it answers your question... If you can search from only the left or right side that could further optimize.

That is functionally similar to `String.Contains`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

**EDIT:** How will you parse the input text into the "relevant" substring?

**EDIT:** To search the same `LIKE` condition but reverse, from your partial column to the complete literal, simply append the wildcard characters:

```
... WHERE 'AB_SYS_20120430.TXT' LIKE '%' + MyColumn + '%'
```

**EDIT:** You have suggested that you can't get it to work. If you add the schema do your question then I can help you further but consider this:

You have a table called MyTable
In that table there is a column called MyColumn
Some rows in that table have the data 'AB_SYS' in MyColumn

Given the parameter 'AB_SYS_20120430.TXT' you want to return all matching rows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTestProcedure 
    @pFullNameString nvarchar(4000) = '' -- parameter passed in, like AB_SYS_20120430.TXT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE
        @pFullNameString LIKE '%' + MyTable.[MyColumn] + '%'
END
GO
```

Comment: That's the issue is I cant parse it into the relevant string.  This is an outlier use case where we want to look anywhere in the string.  Otherwise I would use an in or equals operator once I had the relevant string.  I can't use the contains since I can't turn full-indexing on in the DB.  I would like to be able to handle this in a SQL statement (value passed into a sproc) and not pulling it back to .NET and doing some sting comparison and then passing relevant value in.

Comment: @nonuabiz how do you know what part of the string you want? Like do you want the first 6 characters? Do you want the sting up to the second underscore? If your question is parsing then you have to define the parameters... otherwise why wouldn't a string containing "AB" or even "A" qualify?

Comment: I want the entire string match from the column but where AB_SYS exists anywhere in the string.  So it wouldn't match on A or AB but only an exact match on the literal string value AB_SYS anywhere in the passed string (I.e. AB_SYS_20120430.TXT versus 20120430_AB_SYS.TXT would both return but 20120430_AB_SY.TXT wouldn't for example).  Not much different than saying like 'AB_SYS%' the only different it's being told to look left or right of the string.  I just want it anywhere in the string. The same premise as pulling it down to .NET and using contains on the string.  I.e. Taken from MSDN:

Comment: string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    string s2 = "fox";
    bool b;
    b = s1.Contains(s2);
    Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b);

Comment: @nonuabiz how do you get "AB_SYS" ? Or is that simply what you're searching for? If it is, then you want the `LIKE` function I described.

Comment: AB_SYS is stored in the column.  I am matching the full string passed in against the column.  So where colA (AB_SYS) like '%AB_SYS_04302012.TXT% (value passed in) returns 0 records. As mentioned this can be accomplished using contains in SQL server but this requires full-text indexing to be turned on which there are reservations about turning this on and opening the flood gates for mis-use of this.

Comment: @nonuabiz Ahhh, I see. So you, actually, want the `LIKE` in reverse. It's as simple as re-organzing the query.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  '%AB_SYS_04302012.TXT%' like colA (AB_SYS) returns zero records and '%AB_SYS_04302012.TXT%' like '%' + colA (AB_SYS) + '%' returns zero records.

Comment: @nonuabiz ... see my example in the answer. You only want to wrap your column in the '%'

Comment: This isn't returning either. I also found something using a regex function with CLR integration that may work.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server-2005-2008

Comment: @nonuabiz if it isn't running then there's something wrong with how you're formatting the query. Can you post actual schema and variable names in your question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10719/discussion-between-matthew-pk-and-nonuabiz)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

```
WHERE  CHARINDEX(StringToCheckFor, StringToCheckIn) > 0
```